# Facing issue during upload file in php

Tags: php

i have a project.below is the root directory in CentOs system.

Root Directory:/var/www/html

My Project Folder Name:Desh
 and uploaded script is inside the Desh folder.
i want to upload file the attached file. Below is the code.

FILEREPOSITORY is the destination directory where i want to move the attached file.

```
$tkt_id = mysql_insert_id();
define ('/FILEREPOSITORY','./');
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) 
  {
 $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],     FILEREPOSITORY.'/$tkt_id.zip');
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what i am wrong. The attached file is not moving in FILEREPOSITORY directory.

Comment: Have you change permission to 777 for FILEREPOSITORY folder?

Comment: The first slash (`/`) in `define ('/FILEREPOSITORY','./');` makes no sense...

Comment: @NiketanRaval That permission mode _never_ is a good idea and it _never_ is required. Instead on finds out what permissions actually _are_ required and sets those.

Comment: Thanks Niketan Raval. It was worked after 777 permission

Answer (score 0):

There could be following reason.

1) Check directory permissions [`sudo chmod -R 777 ./`]

2) change `define ('/FILEREPOSITORY','./');` to `define ('FILEREPOSITORY','./');`

3) Replace  `FILEREPOSITORY.'/$tkt_id.zip'` with  `FILEREPOSITORY."/$tkt_id.zip"` or  `FILEREPOSITORY.'/'.$tkt_id.zip`

Answer (score -1):

Use double quate and set permission 777 to FILEREPOSITORY

```
    $tkt_id = mysql_insert_id();
define ('FILEREPOSITORY','./');
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'])) 
  {
 $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],     FILEREPOSITORY."/$tkt_id.zip");
  }
```